# How to deal with backslashes (because of parenthesis) in json using laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

I have text

`This is Laravel's package. Following terms and conditions ("Terms")`

Above text I want to return as json through laravel api, the problem is I am getting string with backslashes because of parenthesis.

I am trying following

```
$content = 'This is Laravel\'s package. Following terms and conditions ("Terms")';
$data =  str_replace(PHP_EOL, '', $content);
echo response()->json([ 'data' => $data ]);
```

Which output is following

```
{"data":"This is Laravel's package. Following terms and conditions (\"Terms\")"}
```

Comment: And what is the problem with it? The string is encased with " on the outside, so it's natural to escape it inside.

Comment: @DanielProtopopov I want to remove backslashes from `(\"Terms\")`

Comment: Hi Imran, if you remove the backslashes then it's not a valid JSON anymore. Can you give us a hint what you're trying to achieve? If you decode the string then you get your initial string without the quotes. Seems totally fine to me.

Comment: @ChristophKluge Thanks, as you can see the line mentioned in the start of my question, I want that text exactly in json.

Comment: have you tried JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES ? example : `response()->json([ 'data' => $data ],200, [], JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES));`

Comment: That's impossible to pass your quoted terms word through a json string without escaping it. It will brake the JSON Standard. But it doens't matter, because on client site any json impl. will return the string without the escape sequence, for sure.